# Confused about accessing mutable dictionary inside an array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm missing something here and I know it's not that hard but I'm not getting it. I have a plist of dictionaries. It's being loaded into a mutable array which then populates my tableView.

plist sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>entry1</string>
        <key>checkedState</key>
        <string>NO</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>accessoriesImage</string>
        <key>checkedState</key>
        <string>NO</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>activationCharge</string>
        <key>checkedState</key>
        <string>NO</string>
    </dict>
```

And I'm trying to access those dictionary values but I'm getting confused.

Here's my initialization:

```
static NSString *kTitleKey = @"title";
static NSString *kCheckedState = @"checkState";

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize attributesTableView, attributesArray;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        NSString *attributesFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"attributesPlist"ofType:@"plist"];

        attributesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:attributesFile];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Skipping to the relevant bits, I'm populating my tableView cells with:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[attributesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:kTitleKey];
```

Later in didSelectRowAtIndexPath I'm trying to check those dictionary values and that's where I'm failing.

Example:

```
if ([[attributesArray valueForKey:kTitleKey = @"All"] valueForKey:kCheckedState = @"YES"]) {
                        [attributesArray setValue:kCheckedState = @"NO" forKey:@"All"];

[attributesArray setValue:kCheckedState = @"YES" forKey:[[attributesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:kTitleKey]];
```

I'm getting this error: **valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key YES.'**

I know I'm just accessing it wrong but I'm not sure how I do that when I'm using a mutable array filled with mutable dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your syntax for setting values is off. In the last code snippet you posted, you have this:

```
[attributesArray valueForKey:kTitleKey = @"All"]
```

Contrary to what you might think, this doesn't set the title to "All"; instead, it *replaces the value of `kTitleKey`* with the string "All", then fetches the value of "All" from the attributes array. Instead, I think you want something like:

```
[attributesArray setValue:@"All" forKey:kTitleKey]
```

You'll have to make similar updates throughout that last example. Remember the critical distinction here:

- `valueForKey:` *gets* a value. You can never set something using `valueForKey:`, even if you throw some equals signs in.
- `setValue:forKey:` *sets* a value. You'll want to use this whenever you need to change `attributesArray`.

You might want to read up on [key-value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) for more information.

Comment: Not sure your answer makes sense. In my last code snippet I'm testing for title = ALL and checkedState = YES. If that's true I'm trying to set checkedState to NO for title ALL. And then I'm setting checkedState to YES for the row that was selected in the table. Two unrelated functions but both doing similar things.

Comment: Ah. In that case, your code is still a little off - recall that Objective-C string equality testing is done by calling `isEqualToString:`, so you might do something like `if([[attributesArray valueForKey:kTitleKey] isEqualToString:@"All"] && ...`.